# iPhone single xib for button and textfield

Tags: iphone, xib

I am having a view controller with one .xib file

On some particular button action, I need to load the view controller with button and on some other button action, I need to load the view with textfield.
Can I do this with single xib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Have two `UIView`s. Add `UITextField` to one `UIView`, say **tView**. Initially make tView hidden. In another `UIView`, say **mView**, add the `UIButton`s. When the particular button action been called, unhide the **tView** and hide **mView**. Hope this is your requirement!!*